# End of recursion specialization of inner template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, specialization

Consider this working code:

```
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename ...> struct A;

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct A<First, Rest...> {
    static void execute() {
        std::cout << typeid(First).name() << ' ';
        A<Rest...>::execute();
    }
};

template <>
struct A<> {
    static void execute() {}  // End of recursion.
};

int main() {
    A<char, bool, int>::execute();  // char bool int
}
```

So why does the end of recursion below not compile (error statements provided in comments):

```
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename ...> struct A;

template <typename... Ts>
struct A {
    template <typename...> struct B;
    template <typename...> static void execute();
};

template <typename... Ts>
template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct A<Ts...>::B<First, Rest...> {
    static void execute() {
        std::cout << typeid(First).name() << ' ';
        B<Rest...>::execute();
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
template <> // invalid explicit specialization before '>' token
struct A<Ts...>::B<> {  // template parameters not used in partial specialization: Ts
    static void execute() {}  // End of recursion
};

template <typename... Ts>
template <typename... Us>
void A<Ts...>::execute() {
    B<Ts..., Us...>::execute();
}

int main() {
    A<char, bool, int>::execute<double, short, float>();
}
```

It does work when I use this end of recursion instead of above:

```
template <typename... Ts>
template <typename Last>
struct A<Ts...>::B<Last> {
    static void execute() {std::cout << typeid(Last).name();}
};
```

But I just want to know what's wrong with the original attempt.  Furthermore, I have to repeat the body of the execute() function using this second way (which of course leads to more maintenance responsibilities).

GCC 4.9.2 states that `A<char, bool, int>::B<>` is an incomplete type.  But I defined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[temp.expl.spec]/p15 prohibits explicit specializating a member template without explicitly specializing each enclosing template as well:

> A member or a member template may be nested within many enclosing class templates. In an explicit specialization for such a member, the member declaration shall be preceded by a `template<>` for each enclosing class template that is explicitly specialized. *[ Example:*
>
> ```c++
> template<class T1> class A {
>     template<class T2> class B {
>         void mf();
>     };
> };
> template<> template<> class A<int>::B<double>;
> template<> template<> void A<char>::B<char>::mf();
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

For example, this code compiles:

```c++
template <>
template <>
struct A<>::B<> {
    static void execute() {}  // End of recursion
};
```

But it does not allow you to use the template parameters from the enclosing class template. A better way to do this would be to use a pack expansion "trick" in the primary template:

```c++
template <typename... Ts>
template <typename... Args>
struct A<Ts...>::B {
    static void execute() {
        using unpack = int[];
        (void)unpack{((std::cout << typeid(Args).name() << ' '), 0)...};
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading this right.  So I replace my `template <>` with `template <> template <>` ?  That does not compile either.  I still need my `A<Ts...>`.

Comment: @prestokeys Yes, there are now two templates being specialized, `A` and `A::B`. edit: Yes, I realize that, I will post an edit.

Comment: Yes, I know that there are workarounds, including this pack expansion trick.  But I'm still trying to understand the language.  Is the original attempt illegal, or is it the compilers overlooking the syntax?

Comment: @prestokeys Yes, the original attempt is illegal. For the reason this is not allowed, I'm not sure of.